# I am getting this crash, again and again from Crashlytics, but can't reproduce locally

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
Crashed: com.IPTV.TVLService.GuideProgramService
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x182a05b90 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x18326f654 CFBasicHashCreateCopy + 668
2  CoreFoundation                 0x183291248 CFDictionaryCreateCopy + 148
3  CFNetwork                      0x18396fa70 URLResponse::createArchiveList(__CFAllocator const*, long*, void const***, long*) + 228
4  CFNetwork                      0x18396f764 URLResponse::copyPropertyList(__CFAllocator const*) + 68
5  CFNetwork                      0x1839c1610 ___ZN12__CFURLCache23CreateAndStoreCacheNodeEP16__CFURLCacheNodePK20_CFCachedURLResponsePK10__CFStringPK13_CFURLRequestPKvbRb_block_invoke + 796
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x182dd94bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x182dd947c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x182de54c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x182ddcf80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x182de7390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x182de70b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182ff1470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182ff1020 start_wqthread + 4
```

I am new to iOS development.

How to understand what's causing issue? Please help me with any document or book that help me to learn solving this issues for future.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code to describe your programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your app crashed in thread com.IPTV.TVLService.GuideProgramService and whether this thread is a custom thread or not? 
Are you develop on tvOS?
There is something you should offer to make your question clear.

Comment: if the question is not clear to you, there is no need to give any answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Its not custom thread, there's service (subclass of NSOperation) added in another operation queue. Crashlogs, are of iOS application only.

Can you tell help me with more precise info needed?

Comment: @JaykumarGurnani For example, your crash method name? Your custom code that might cause this crash? Or even your module's function or business logic? Or even your demo project. Whatever might help others solve your problem.>^<